# Any reasons why Teleriks RadWindow confirm dialog button events are not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I can't go into details on this one.
This confirm dialogs is working perfectly for all users except for one specific user logging in to the samen environment using the exact same internet explorer settings.

This is where the confirm dialog gets created:

```
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" 
                    CommandName="CloseObject" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" 
                    ConfirmText="Are you sure?" 
                    ConfirmTitle="Warning" 
                    FilterControlAltText="Filter CloseObject column" 
                    ImageUrl="~/Images/close.gif" Text="Close this object?" 
                    UniqueName="CloseObject">
                    <ItemStyle Width="16px" />
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

And this is my RadWindowsManager:

```
    <telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" 
        EnableShadow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false"
        ReloadOnShow="true" Modal="True" EnableViewState="false">       
        <Localization No="Nee" Yes="Ja"/>     
        <ConfirmTemplate>
            <div class="rwDialogPopup radconfirm">
                <div class="rwDialogText">
                    {1}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(true);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[Yes]##</span></span></a>
                    <a onclick="$find('{0}').close(false);" class="rwPopupButton" href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <span class="rwOuterSpan"><span class="rwInnerSpan">##LOC[No]##</span></span></a>                              
                </div>
            </div>
        </ConfirmTemplate>
    </telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

The buttons are linked up with the correct actions and work all the time, but in this case, after the confirm dialog has opened the buttons do not respond to clicks by the user.

Which would be the most common errors in this case, any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure there are no script errors prior to the button clicks
2. make sure the browser is not in quirks mode (you need valid HTML and you can also add an X-UA Compatible meta tag to put IE in Edge mode)
3. make sure  Active Scripting is not disabled in IE's Internet Options for that user